# python function as parameter to c++ exposed class using ::boost::python

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

Ive been working with Python and C++ together for some time, but never tried to implement what follows:

Id like the python user to be able to write something like:

```
def foo(a,b):
    return a+b

myclass.myfunc(foo)
```

where myclass is a c++ class exposed to python with Boost.Python, with one of its methods (myfunc) that takes a function with:

```
int func(int,int)
```

signature, and only that.

Is this possible?

Im thinking about declaring:

```
myclass::myfunc(boost::python::object)
```

and extracting the typedef'ed function signature, but im just guessing..

maybe there's a better/feasible way to do this, maybe with some 'function' object?

Comment: maybe a better title would have been 'python function as parameter to boost::python c++ exposed class'

Comment: This is an interesting question and I'm curious to see the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pretty much guessed the answer. Python functions are indeed just `boost::python::object` instances. You can then just have a `boost::function<int (int, int)>` and put the Python object inside that.

I just installed my OS and I don't have Boost yet, so I can't test it, but I think it will work if you just do this (without any wrapper functions):

```
void function(boost::function<int (int, int)> func) {
    // ...
}

// And then you expose the function as you normally would
```

I expect the above to work; if it doesn't this surely will:

```
void function_wrap(boost::python::object func)
{
    auto lambda = [func](int a, int b) -> int {
        return boost::python::extract<int>(func(a, b));
    };
    function(boost::function<int (int, int)>(lambda));
}

// And then you expose the wrapper, not the original function
```

Comment: that is what i was after.. ill test it asap and post results, thank you

Comment: Interesting. What does `::boost::python` do if `func` is not a callable? I presume ::boost::python::object has a templated version of `operator ()` to make this work.

Comment: @Omnifarious Yes, there's a templated `operator()`. In case the object is not callable there's an exception thrown (I can't remember what it was called) — pretty much the same thing that happens when you try to call an uncallable object in Python.

Comment: @PaulManta: `::boost::python` is almost scary in how well it's put together.

Comment: @Omnifarious Indeed. I guess you could call it inspiring how hard it it is use the Python C API and yet how easy it is to use Boost.Python.

Comment: Ok.. so: the first one doesnt work, it (predictably) complains about not having a converter to get a boost::function from a boost::python::object, then I upgraded to g++ 4.5 (in order o use lambdas) and works great. Now, can you tell me exactly how can it be? please forgive my ignorance.. but even if I know about lambdas I cant figure it out WHY it does work.. and whats that function() at the last line? Thanx in advance

Comment: just to be more precise: I dont understand why I have to use a lambda function and not just write something like: int k=boost::python::extract<int>(func(int,int));

Comment: @user815129 `function` is your original function; `function_wrap` is a helper function that makes your C++ code compatible with Python. Your original function expects to receive a function object, so you can't pass it an int; instead you pass it a lambda that will call the `python::object` and convert its return type to int.

Comment: @user815129 In case you don't need your C++ code to be agnostic of Python, you can get rid of the wrapper by making the original function take a `python::object` as a parameter instead of a `boost::function`.

Comment: ah-ahh.. Yes, now I see.. Thank you... what if func returns void? could I declare: auto lambda = [func](int a,int b) { func(a,b); }; and just change boost::function declaration?

Comment: @user815129 `func` can't return void, Python functions always return something (even if that something is `None`). However, it is your job to ensure that what is returned can be converted to an int.